# Python - MongoDB - TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter

The information I am looking for is the sum of the amount of retweets in a MongoDB where the text contains 'spiderman' or 'spider-man'
I am running into an issue where I loaded twitter information into a MongoDB into a database named db and a collection called spiderman. I then created a variable using the following code:

```
#Runs successful

tweetsSpider = spiderman.find() 

#Runs succesfsful 

twSpider = [tweet for tweet in tweetsSpider]

#Created the following function to test out the information --RUNS SUCCESSFUL--
def print_tweet_data(tweets):
    for tweet in tweets:
        print('\nDate:', tweet['created_at'])
        print('From:', tweet['user']['name'])
        print('Message', tweet['text'])
        print('Retweets:', tweet['retweet_count'])

print_tweet_data(twSpider[:1])
```

The output of my last code is the following:

Date: Sun Nov 22 00:27:02 +0000 2020

From: Ric

Message RT @KarnivallRose: Going to be painting this soon! I’ll be live on stream to paint it but I need to find what I want on it first! #art #pai…

Retweets: 1

```
count = 0
def retweet_data(tweets):
    for tweet in tweets:
        if 'spider' in tweet['text'] & count <= tweet['retweet_count']:
            print ('The number of retweets that contained SpiderMan:', [sum(tweet['retweet_count'])])
```

I am getting the following error when trying to use the function when trying to use twSpider with the function the error is as follows

"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'"

I tried to modify the code to just sum the values and I got an error as well (Code work

```
count = 0
def retweet_data(tweets):
    for tweet in tweets:
        if count <= tweet['retweet_count']:
            print ('The number of retweets that contained SpiderMan:', [sum(tweet['retweet_count'])])
```

The error is below and I am unsure how to fix! Please help for both!!!

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: how about convert `tweet['retweet_count']` to int?

Comment: Use your favorite debugger or print statements to inspect the values of variables in your program and verify they are what you expect including the types.